# how to set height of tinymce textarea

Tags: css, tinymce

cannot set the height of tinymce textarea. According to [documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@height/), it should be the same as the height of the original replaced textarea, in my case - 500px.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#texedit",
    body_class: 'tiny01',
    content_css: "content.css",
});
```

**content.css**

```
.tiny01{
    background:lightgreen;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:500px;  // deosn't work
}

#texedit{
    height:500px;  // deosn't work
}
```

**main.css**

```
#texedit{
    height:500px;  // deosn't work
}
```

`texedit` is not 500px but about 100px height.

Comment: Set the height in the `init` options. `tinymce.init({height:500})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css file add your id and assign a height

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#mytextarea"
});
```

```css
#mytextarea {
  height: 700px;
  /*edit this*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/tinymce/4.1.2/tinymce.min.js">
</script>
<textarea id="mytextarea">Congratulations!</textarea>
```

Comment: what is wrong with my code, pls. `selector` is there, `id` inside css is there... why it doesn't work in my case ?

Comment: have you try taking out `body_class`?

Comment: it's possible that you're not retrieving any class styles back from your css file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set this value in the init call.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#texedit",
    body_class: 'tiny01',
    content_css: "content.css",
    height: "500"
});
```